# Add tablespace for existing table in DB2

Tags: database, db2, alter-table, tablespace

I am using DB2 in my project. I have a table which has following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
            ID INTEGERT NOT NULL,
            ACCESS_INFO VARCHAR (2048) NOT NULL,
            NAME VARCHAR (2048))
```

When trying to create index for the column "ACCESS_INFO", am getting following error:

```
The index or index extension "xxxx" cannot be created or altered because the combined length of the specified columns is too long..
```

I referred [1] which explains to add large tablespace for creating indexes for long column. But this for new tables. What is the proper way to add it for an existing table?

[1] https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19894/create-index-for-long-columns

Comment: What is the Db2-server operating system (z/OS, i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows) ?

Comment: @mao, OS is Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0614n) for SQL0614N explains this clearly, a 4K pagesize tablespace allows max 1K key-length, an 8KB pagesize tablespace allows a 2k max key length,  16KB pagesize allows max 4k key-length,  32kb pagesize allows max 8kb key length.

You can recreate your table in the next higher pagesize to avoid this issue.

I assume you are using a 4Kb pagesize tablespace (this is the default), so the next higher pagesize is 8KB.

Create (or re-use suitable existing) an 8KB pagesize bufferpool ([CREATE BUFFERPOOL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000912.html) )
Create (or re-use suitable existing) an 8KB tablespace ([CREATE TABLESPACE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000929.html)) to use the new bufferpool of matching pagesize.

If the table contains data already that you don't want to reload, then use the stored procedure [ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055069.html) to move the existing data to new tablespace(s).

If the table contains no rows (or can be quickly reloaded), drop the table and recreate with modified DDL to add `IN $your_8kb_tablespace`.

If the table will contain many millions of rows, it is wise to split it over three tablespaces (one for data,  one for indexes, one for long data) - you can also do this with the `create table` statement, refer to the documentation for details.

For very large tables consider using range-partitioning and hash-partitioning if licensing and hardware allows that.